compute variance given by this integral
If $x_{1},x_{2},\dots,x_{n}$ is a random sample from the distribution on the positive real numbers with density $$\theta^{2}xe^{-\theta x} $$  for fixed $\theta > 0$, I want to show that the variance of  $$\tilde{\theta}=\frac{2n-1}{\sum_{i}x_{i}}$$ is $$\frac{\theta^{2}}{2(n-1)}.$$
Since I already know the expectation of $\tilde{\theta}$ is $\theta$, this requires me to compute the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dots\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\sum_{i}x_{i})^{2}}x_{1}x_{2}\dots x_{n}\exp\left({-\theta \sum_{i}x_{i}}\right)dx_{1}dx_{2}\dots dx_{n}.$$
I don't know how to compute this. The most I was able to do is to make  a substitution to get
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{u_n}^{\infty}\dots\int_{u_2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u_1^{2}}(u_{1}-u_{2})\dots(u_{n-1}-u_n)u_n\exp({-\theta u_1})du_{1}du_{2}\dots du_{n}$$

As a sketch:
each $X_i$ has a Gamma distribution with shape $2$ and rate $\theta$;
so $\sum  X_i$ has a Gamma distribution with shape $2n$ and rate $\theta$;
and $\frac{1}{\sum  X_i}$ has an Inverse-Gamma distribution with shape $2n$ and scale $\theta$;
so $\frac{1}{\sum  X_i}$ has a variance $\frac{\theta^2}{(2n-1)^2(2n-2)}$ when $n>1$;
so $\frac{2n-1}{\sum  X_i}$ has a variance $\frac{\theta^2}{2n-2}$ when $n>1$.

ah interesting, thank you so much! @Henry
